# ASP.NET CORE web application doesn't use .css styles when run using dotnet command

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, dotnetcorecli

I have a ASP .NET CORE application, targeted in verion 6.0.
When I run it from Visual Studio it looks great, but when I run it using `dotnet` command:

```
dotnet webApplication1.dll
```

it looks like no .css styles or .js scripts where found and used.
I searched this documentation but cannot find the hint how to include styles path.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong command
You should use.

```
dotnet run
```

If you want to use the dotnet command you should publish you app before in order to have all the misc files.

You need to do :

```
dotnet publish
```

Before running the app using

```
dotnet Webapp.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by manually copying `wwwroot` folder to the `\bin\Debug\net6.0` directory. For some reasons it is not being copied there automatically.